# getElementsByTagName Is Not Changing Color

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way like css, that we can change color with javascript to tags, I tried getElementsByTagName but nothing happens.

I tried searching google but unfortunately not found, that's why I am asking this basic javascript question here, thanks for your answer in advance...

This code is not working...

HTML:

```
<p id="demo"> test test test test test</p>

<span id="demoz"> test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('demo').style.background = "green";

document.getElementsByTagName('span').style.background = "green";
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3j0vokLd/

Comment: That's because it will return an array of elements just like `getElementsByClassName()` try `document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.background = "green";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` will yield an array-like object (well, you can have multiple `span` tags on one page, right?).

To change the background color of each (span) element returned by this function, you would iterate over the returned array (-like object):

```
var spanElements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spanElements.length; i++) {
    spanElements[i].style.background = 'green';
}
```

[See the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j0vokLd/1/)

Or, if you are just targeting a single span element, the first in the returned array, you could do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.background = 'green';
```

Comment: probably should be `.backgroundColor`, not just `.background`

Answer (score 3):

It returns a `NodeList`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.background = "green";
```

Comment: I believe the index should be 0. First and only element in the array.

Comment: Of course, if there aren't any spans on the page, then this will crash when you try to access the array index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/gj0g5ysr/

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

GetElementsByTagName returns a collection, which is like an array

Comment: its not like an array...Its actually an Array

Comment: Perhaps, but they only call it a collection here, which sometimes means there may be a difference:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: @user3089840 @TusharGupta : Don't use [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/), use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). You'll note [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is not an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but an array-like object.

Comment: @TusharGupta no it is not an Array.

Comment: Yeah, MDN is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `document.querySelector()` with selector `"span[id=demoz"])` to specify `span` element having attribute `id="demoz"` to set `background`

```js
document.getElementById("demo").style.background = "green";

document.querySelector("span[id=demoz]").style.background = "green";
```

```html
<p id="demo"> test test test test test</p>

<span id="demoz"> test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3j0vokLd/3/

Comment: Nice.  So much more concise.